# Междометие А-а

Tags: междометие

Как правильно пишется "А-а"? Дефис, тире, длинное тире? Буквально сегодня встретил написание с обычным тире и пробелами. Мне кажется, оно не верно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Междометие "А-а" пишется через дефис.